# Complex variables: The conjugate of a polynomial $\overline{p(z)}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R} = p(\overline{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not sure how best to begin.  Should I use polar form?  I tried this and got really fuzzy results.  I need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Just use $\overline{ab} = \bar a\bar b$, so $\overline{a_kz^k}=$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Write the polynomial as $p(z) = \sum a_k z^k$. Then take the conjugate of $p$ in this form. Use the properties of the conjugation and finally that $a_k$ is real.